Way to share flags between different tasks defined in deno.json?
Various flags for permissions and other things have to be identical for the run and compile calls. If I additionally have a watch script, everything gets duplicated three times, e.g.
"tasks": {
    "start": "deno run --allow-net --allow-env --allow-read --allow-write --allow-run --cert certs/cert.pem src/main.ts",
    "watch": "deno run --allow-net --allow-env --allow-read --allow-write --allow-run --cert certs/cert.pem --watch src/main.ts",
    "build": "deno compile --output dist/thing.exe --allow-net --allow-env --allow-read --allow-write --allow-run --cert certs/cert.pem src/main.ts"
}

Is there a simple way to reduce this duplication?
I had hoped that there would be a config option for permissions, but did not find such a thing.

I have found a way, though it is a bit of a hack:
"tasks": {
    "start": "deno run $(deno task flags) src/main.ts",
    "watch": "deno run $(deno task flags) --watch src/main.ts",
    "build": "deno compile --output dist/thing.exe $(deno task flags) src/main.ts",
    "flags": "echo --allow-net --allow-env ..."
}

